# Filtrar datos de una tabla y alternar color en filas con CSS y JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Estoy trabajando con un sistema y estoy en la parte en la que tengo que filtrar datos que muestro en la tabla, dicha tabla usa las pseudo clases **nth-child(odd)** y **nth-child(even)** para alternar colores en las filas.

El problema aquí es que cuando hago el filtreo no alterna los colores en las filas que se están visualizando, dejo lo que tengo hasta el momento:

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var contenido_fila;
var coincidencias;
var exp;
var codigoAscci;

$(document).ready(function() {
  obtenerNotas();

  $("#parametroVal").on("keyup", function(){
      var parametro = $(this).val();

      if(!checkTeclaDel(event))
      {
          if(parametro.length >= 1)
           filtrar(parametro);
      }
  });
});

function filtrar(cadena)
{ 
    $("#tabla_notas tbody tr").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("ocultar");

        contenido_fila = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text();

        exp = new RegExp(cadena, 'gi');
        coincidencias = contenido_fila.match(exp);

        if(coincidencias == null)
        {
            contenido_fila = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();

            exp = new RegExp(cadena, 'gi');
            coincidencias = contenido_fila.match(exp);

            if(coincidencias == null)
                $(this).addClass("ocultar");
        }
    });
}

function mostrarFilas()
{
    $("#tabla_notas tbody tr").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("ocultar");
    });
}

function checkTeclaDel(e)
{
    codigoAscci = e.which;

    if(codigoAscci == 8)
    {
        if($("#parametroVal").val().length >= 1)
            filtrar($("#parametroVal").val());
        else
            mostrarFilas();

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

function obtenerNotas()
{
    var mes = $("#mesVal").val();
    var ano = $("#anoVal").val();   

    $.post("../includes/acciones/control_nota/get_notas.php", {mes:mes, ano:ano}, function(data){
        $("#div_notas").html(data);
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #c7d1dd;
}
</style>
```

Agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas rehacer el efecto `css` de las filas al final de o tras la función `filtrar`.

Para emular el efecto de tu código he creado una función ocultar que esconde filas y hace el efecto añadiendo una clase `css`. También es necesario comprobar que no tiene la clase que produce el efecto `css` contrario por un ocultar/filtrado anterior.

```js
function ocultar(a) {
  $("#row"+a).addClass("ocultar");
  
//esta es la parte a incluir en la función filtrar
  var counter = 0;
  $("#tabla_notas tbody tr").each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("ocultar")) {
     //console.log("hide");
    } else {
     counter ++;
     //console.log(counter);
     if (counter%2 == 0) {
      $(this).addClass("tr-odd");
      if ($(this).hasClass("tr-even")) { $(this).removeClass("tr-even"); }
     } else {
      $(this).addClass("tr-even");
      if ($(this).hasClass("tr-odd")) { $(this).removeClass("tr-odd"); }
     }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #c7d1dd;
}

.tr-even { background-color: #ffffff !important; } 
.tr-odd { background-color: #c7d1dd !important; }

.ocultar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla_notas">
  <tr id="row1"> 
    <td>Fila 1</td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="ocultar(1)" value="ocultar"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2"> 
    <td>Fila 2</td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="ocultar(2)" value="ocultar"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3"> 
    <td>Fila 3</td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="ocultar(3)" value="ocultar"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4"> 
    <td>Fila 4</td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="ocultar(4)" value="ocultar"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row5"> 
    <td>Fila 5</td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="ocultar(5)" value="ocultar"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```